# Onward at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: adverbs

I want to say something like: from now on I will work on my second task.

Is it correct to use "onward" (just onward) at the beginning of the sentence to replace "from now on"?

**Onward,** I will work on my second task.

Edit: To give context to this sentence (requested on the comments) - the sentence should express future plans in a sequence of events (which is tasks completions). By *future plans* I don't set a specific time in the future but wish to imply to the near future - in  an hour, by tomorrow etc.

Something like: "I have now completed my first task, and I am about to start my work on the second task."

Comment: make it plural ***Onwards**, I will work on my second task.*

Comment: @Jeeped: That **s** isn't a "plural". But thanks for making the comment, which prompted me to look deeper into the issue. You're quite right that ***onwards*** with an ***s*** is far more common for this exact context, but I was truly surprised to find that the evidence from Google NGrams on this one shows that *unlike all other similar usages*, this is one where the preference is the same on both sides of the pond. But I have no idea why this *exact* context should be different. It certainly wasn't something I expected to find.

Comment: [*Onward, Chistian soldiers!*](https://www.lds.org/music/library/hymns/onward-christian-soldiers?lang=eng&_r=1)

Comment: For a single-word replacement of "from now on", you could use ["henceforth"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/henceforth).

Comment: @Hellion I'm not convinced that "henceforth" expresses the intended meaning here. Nor am I sure about "onward(s)" either. Both would seem to apply to something you intend to do in perpetuity. But here we are simply talking about "my second task".  One wouldn't normally say "Henceforth/onwards I will write a letter", but one might say "Henceforth/onwards I will give up eating kippers in bed".

Comment: @WS2: We don't have the full context, so we don't know *exactly* what alternative might be suitable. For example, *I'll finish Task1 tomorrow, and **thenceforth** I'll work on Task2* kinda makes syntactic sense to me, but ***henceforth*** is a complete no-no in that context. Another credible alternative (that works for Past *and* Future contexts) is *I finished Task1 last Monday, and **thereafter** I worked on Task2*.

Comment: If you just mean to say that you’re starting the 2nd task now, neither of your alternatives expresses that. Please [edit] your question to describe what you’re trying to express.

Comment: It's not a usage that is particularly idiomatic.  "Onward" is becoming a hair archaic, and is generally only used in a few idiom-like structures (eg, "from this day onward").

Comment: @WS2 Your point is a good one. It's the *will* that makes it unusual, not *onward* itself. Perhaps, *Onward (now) to my second task* would be better.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and comments. I added context to the original question.

Answer (score 3):

**Onward** sounds odd and is uncommon at the start of a sentence.

Here's the definition of *onward* in the Oxford English Dictionary, adverb, entry 4b.

> In an uninterrupted advance or succession forward in time. Cf. on adv. 4a.

The definition of *on* referred to is the same *on* used in the adverbial phrase "from now on." So the two have some relation to one another.

My issue with your example is that "onward" isn't an adverb commonly used at the beginning of a sentence to modify that entire sentence. In the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), it appears at the beginning of the sentence in a different sense: proceeding forward in *space* to a destination. "Onward!" appears. "Onward to [some goal]" appears. "Onward [people being urged forward]" appears. No start-of-sentence "Onward, I ..." formation appears. The closest that appears is "from that moment onward, I ..." That last usage highlights that, when "onward" is used in a temporal sense as an adverb at the start of a sentence, it tends to be incorporated into an adverbial phrase that gives more context. So in usage, *onward* at the start of a sentence usually comes with some extra information: *from what* or *to what*?

Given that evidence, I would use "from now on" if I wanted to be perceived as correct and "onward" only if I had some deliberate purpose in mind.

Answer (score 2):

No, the cited usage is *not* idiomatic. Use something like *[**From now onwards,**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=From+now+onwards%2CFrom+now+onward&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CFrom%20now%20onwards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CFrom%20now%20onward%3B%2Cc0) I will do that*.

If you compare AmE and BrE corpuses on that link, you'll see that *both* massively favour ***onwards*** over ***onward*** in that exact context - which I found interesting, given that AmE always favours ***toward*** over ***towards*** (with Brits it's the other way around).

A bit more sniffing around showed me that Brits are about equally divided over whether to include the **s** or not in a "phrasal verb" context such as [***to move onward / onwards***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to%20move%20onward%2Cto%20move%20onwards&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20move%20onward%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20move%20onwards%3B%2Cc0) - but in *that* context, Americans much more definitely prefer ***to move onward***.

So regardless of what you read about the "standard" US/UK distinction (telling us that the "s-less" versions ***toward, upward, downward, onward*** are used in AmE, whereas ***towards, upwards, downwards, onwards*** are "British"), this doesn't seem to be true for OP's exact context *(from now / then **onwards**)*.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the sentence as it is. Saying that you *must* change it is too prescriptive. It would be more commonly used in a changed form, but it's certainly not ungrammatical if left alone.

Comment: I did specifically say "not idiomatic", not "not grammatical". But in deference to your point, I've changed my potentially overprescriptive "You need... " to a mere recommendation. But I have to say that the *exact* cited usage is ***so*** non-idiomatic it would be unwise to encourage a nns to think it could be in any way "acceptable". You can validly start a sentence with ***onward(s)*** in contexts like imperative ***Onward Christian soldiers!*** or ***Onward we marched***, where it denotes "direction", but not when it's a "temporal" reference.

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct to use "onward" (just onward) at the beginning of the sentence to replace "from now on"?

> **Onward**, I will work on my second task.

Yes, it is grammatically correct, as is the more used *onwards*.